# how I can set color of anything in css

Tags: html, css, colors

How can I set color of anything in css, I want to set color once on body and see result on anything like fonts, borders, hr and etc. how do I must do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*{
color: #fff;
background: #000;
}
```

Also you can use the `inherit` value which will inherit the values from the parent.

```
body{
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
}
.inner_element{
    color: inherit;
    background: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For body background color**

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_bgcolor.asp

**for changing text color**

http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Text-Color-in-HTML

```
<p>Lorem ipsum <font color = "40E0D0">dolores</font> sit amet.</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WPgt9/26/#update

Comment: Try to post more info in your answer, don't just post links unless it's in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do one of the following:

```
.myCssClass
{
color:blue;
}
```

or

```
#myTagId
{
 color:#00ff00;
}
```

etc.

You can set color either by name (blue, red, etc.), by hexa (#090909) or by rgb ( rgb(255,0,0) ).

Also, you have to apply the css class in your html markup.
You can also define css for a tag type:

```
body
{
color:red;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to define the colors one time on the body and everything will inherit it automatically unless you specify otherwise.**

CSS:

```
body{
    color: red;
    background: orange;
    border-color:#fff; //you don't want to set a border on the body, just the color
    etc: #369369;
}
```

Unless you specify in another rule, that should carry through all your elements.

This would override the above text color since it's more specific.

```
p{
    color: #000;
}
```

Visit this link if you want to learn more about CSS specificity, and how rules can override one another.

http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/